# Rights to using App Engine section in Google Cloud Console

Tags: google-app-engine

In the Permission sections I gave access to my brother's e-mail account, but no matter what kind of right is it (View, Edit, Admin), he can't see the App Engine section, which is visible only when logging with the email, I created App Engine project with.

Is there really no way to give my brother rights at least to view logs?

Comment: Well for now Appengine gives only these 3 permission, so if you want just view you Application.. You can assign his email. View Permission.

Comment: Still he can't view the logs which is the point

Comment: In this case then you need to provide him the Edit Privilege.. But remember if you give this privilege. one can deploy and can change the application as well. He cannot delete the application and cannot add any more users as well..

Comment: This is what I'm talking about, I grant him Edit, or even Admin privilege but he still can't see the App Engine section (we did removed browser cache, even used another browser)

Comment: Did you enabled it from Cloud Console **https://code.google.com/apis/console** of that particular email or from Domain Admin to allow appengine applications.

Comment: There is a bug, I explained it in the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there is a bug here. **Adding privileges from new Cloud Console doesn't work**, but when I did that from the old one, Invitation was sent, and now everything works like expected.

Adding edit permission from the new console, allows the user to deploy the app, but doesn't grant him rights to view App Engine section in the console, which sounds like a bug to me.